# Rewrite pretty URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, api, mod-rewrite

I use this project https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api to build an APIs server, but I don't know how to rewrite a pretty URL.

I want my URL from

> domain.com/api.php/xxxx -> domain.com/xxxx

I tried to use this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Is `AllowOverride All` set and `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: thanks for your help @Mike. this config in php.ini file ?

Comment: No, it would need to be set in the relevant Apache config files. What environment are you running? XAMPP? Linux? You can also just test your `.htaccess` file by adding random/junk text at the top of the file and see if your site throws an Internal Server Error. If it does, then you know that it is indeed working.

Comment: i running xampp, it don't throws an internal server error when i add ramdom text in .htaccess

Comment: Okay, so then it is not enabled. You need to ensure that `AllowOverride` is set to `All` in your virtual host configuration (I assume you have already set this up as you seem to be using the `domain.com` virtual host) and you need to ensure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled in your `xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf` file.